# Defining a method that determines whether elements in an array are negative, prime, or perfect squares

Tags: java, arrays, interface, contains, primes

I'm trying to write a code in Java that that can take an array of integers and determine if the array contains elements that are prime, perfect squares, or negative, using a defined method, called `contains`. The method takes an array of integers and returns true if there exists any item in the array that satisfies a specified condition. For instance, the following code fragment:

```
int[] input = {100, 37, 49};

boolean result1 = contains(input, new Prime( ));
boolean result2 = contains(input, new PerfectSquare( ));
boolean result2 = contains(input, new Negative( ));
```

`result1` would return true since 37 is prime, `result2` would also return true since 100 and 49 are perfect squares, and `result3` would return false because none of the elements are negative. The code needs to implement:

- an interface used to specify the second parameter to contains.
- the `contains` method itself (which is a static method).
- the classes Negative, Prime, and Perfect Square.

My main problems are determining how to write the contains method and the Prime and PerfectSquare classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I'm just not really sure how to define a prime number or a perfect square within java. I'm really looking for an algorithm that can determine if any given number is a prime, and an algorithm that determines if a number is a perfect square. Those are my main issues. I'm sorry if I'm not being very clear, it's my first time posting a question here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primes+java try this link. :)

Comment: Not knowing the algorithms for prime or perfect-square numbers isn't a Java problem, it's a math problem.  There are very, very good algorithms for it on Wikipedia, and translating them to Java isn't difficult to do.  At least for the perfect square, I'll give you a hint:  You want a value X such that `(int)sqrt(X*X) == X`.

Comment: also this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays+java+interface

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a number is prime,you need to divide the number by every number from 1 to the square root of that number.

```
static boolean isPrime(int num){
for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(num);i++){
if (num%i==0)//if you can divide him by a number other than 1 and himself return false
return false
         }
return true;

}
```

To determine if a number is Perfect square,just do its square root and check if it is an int

```
static boolean isPerfectRoot(int num){
double sqrt=Math.sqrt(num);
int casting=(int)(sqrt);//cast it to an int
if(sqrt%casting==0)
return true;
else
return false


}
```

I assume you know how to write a method isNegative(). You can call those 3 methods from within your contains method. Your contain method must basically loop through the array and call the 3 methods on each input. 
What do you need the classes for,it makes no sense especially that you are not giving them any arguments,can you clarify your intentions?